# While running this code I'm not getting any lambda value, it isd always 0

Tags: c, math

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    double f,n,xm,sum=0;    
    const double PI = 3.14159;
    
    printf("Enter the Value of 'f'(CM) : ");
    
    scanf("%lf",&f);
    
    for (double i = 1; i < 8; i++)
    {
       printf("\nEnter the Value of 2Xm(cm) : ");        
       scanf("%lf",&n);        
       xm = (n/2);
    
       printf("%lf",i);
    
       double theta = atan(xm/f);        
       double theta_m = theta * ( 180.0 / PI );        
       double sine_theta = sin(theta);                
       double lambda = (0.0000508*sine_theta)/(i);
    
    
       printf("\nXm : %.2lf",xm);        
       printf("\nTheta : %.4lf",theta_m);        
       printf("\nSine Theta(m) : %.4lf",sine_theta);
       printf("\nlambda : %.4lf",lambda);
       printf("");
       sum+=lambda;        
    }
    
    return 0;   
}
```

Use these values:

- f = 85
- xm = 2.2, 4.4, 6.7 or 9

lambda value for 'f = 2.2' should be around 6.5532e-07, for 6.7 = 6.671733333333333e-07, and so on.

But its showing 0 everytime.

Comment: `6.5532e-07` is `0.00000065532`. Try a different format: `"%g"` or `"%.12f"`

Comment: `%.4f` would print 4 decimals, right? What happens when the first 6 decimals are zero?

Comment: OT: Consider [`atan2(xm, f)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/atan2) instead of `atan(xm/f)`.

Comment: @Bob__ not "consider". Just "use". `atan(x/y)` is always wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just increase your printf precision for the double variable lambda.

```
printf("\nlambda : %.12lf",lambda);
```

using precisions lower than 6 would only show you zeros because lambda < 1e-6 in your examples.